# WPF невозможно обновить элемент окна

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, изображения, imagesource

Использовал слайдер на `DispatcherTimer` внутри кода окна. Но после переноса в отдельный Singleton класс потоков управляющих кэшированием картинок и смены слайда выскакивает ошибка.

Помогите побороть эту ошибку возникающую при передачи изображения в форму. Не понимаю, что делаю не так. Вроде оформил доступ к окну через делегат. И вроде подобные структуры работают нормально с текстовыми полями формы, но с изображением нет.

Код MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private delegate void slideCacheUpdateDelegate(int slide, BitmapImage image);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        SlideCache.getInstance.init();

        InitializeComponent();

        // Initial slide cache updater delegate.
        SlideCache.OnRefresh += (s, i) =>
        {
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                changeToNextSlide(s, i);
            else
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new slideCacheUpdateDelegate(changeToNextSlide), new object[] { s, i });
        };

        SlideCache.getInstance.startSlideShow();
    }

    private void changeToNextSlide(int slide, BitmapImage image)
    {
        switch (slide)
        {
            case 1:
                this.imageSlide2.Source = image;
                DoubleAnimation animationSlide1 = new DoubleAnimation();
                animationSlide1.From = 0;
                animationSlide1.To = 1;
                animationSlide1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
                this.imageSlide2.BeginAnimation(Canvas.OpacityProperty, animationSlide1);
                break;

            case 2:
                this.imageSlide1.Source = image;
                DoubleAnimation animationSlide2 = new DoubleAnimation();
                animationSlide2.From = 1;
                animationSlide2.To = 0;
                animationSlide2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
                this.imageSlide2.BeginAnimation(Canvas.OpacityProperty, animationSlide2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SlideShow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="100" Background="Black">
            <Image Name="imageSlide1" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Name="imageSlide2" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код SlideCache.cs:

```
public class SlideCache
{
    public delegate void Slider(int slide, BitmapImage holder);
    public static event Slider OnRefresh;

    private static volatile SlideCache INSTANCE;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private Thread _threadCache;
    private Thread _threadSlide;

    private Dictionary<int, BitmapHolder> _images;

    private int _currentSlide;

    private Boolean _isFirstImage;

    private SlideCache()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public void init()
    {
        initDictionary();

        _currentSlide = 0;
        _isFirstImage = true;

        _threadCache = new Thread(slideCache);
        _threadCache.IsBackground = true;
        _threadCache.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        _threadCache.Start();
    }

    private void slideShow()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ++_currentSlide;
            if (_images[_currentSlide] != null)
            {
                slideUpdate(_isFirstImage ? 1 : 2, _images[_currentSlide].getImage());
                _isFirstImage = !_isFirstImage;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    private void slideCache()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                int slideId = i + 1;
                BitmapHolder holder = _images[slideId];
                if (holder == null || holder.getTimestamp() < timestamp)
                {
                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.BeginInit();
                    image.UriSource = new Uri("http://example.com/slide_" + slideId);
                    image.EndInit();

                    if (holder != null && holder.getImage() != null && image.PixelWidth == 1)
                        continue;

                    _images[slideId] = new BitmapHolder(timestamp.AddSeconds(new Random().Next(180, 600)), image);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void initDictionary()
    {
        _images = new Dictionary<int, BitmapHolder>(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            _images.Add((i + 1), null);
    }

    private void slideUpdate(int slide, BitmapImage image)
    {
        OnRefresh.Invoke(slide, image);
    }

    public void startSlideShow()
    {
        _threadSlide = new Thread(slideShow);
        _threadSlide.IsBackground = true;
        _threadSlide.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        _threadSlide.Start();
    }

    public void stopSlideShow()
    {
        _threadSlide.Abort();
    }

    public void changeToNextSlide(int slide)
    {
        _currentSlide = slide;
        slideUpdate(_isFirstImage ? 1 : 2, _images[_currentSlide].getImage());
        _isFirstImage = !_isFirstImage;
    }

    public Boolean slideShowEnabled()
    {
        return _threadSlide.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running;
    }

    public static SlideCache getInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (INSTANCE == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (INSTANCE == null)
                        INSTANCE = new SlideCache();
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

Код BitmapHolder.cs:

```
public class BitmapHolder
{
    private DateTime _timestamp;
    private BitmapImage _image;

    public BitmapHolder(DateTime timestamp, BitmapImage image)
    {
        _timestamp = timestamp;
        _image = image;
    }

    public DateTime getTimestamp()
    {
        return _timestamp;
    }

    public BitmapImage getImage()
    {
        return _image;
    }
}
```

При запуске приложение зависает и выскакивает следущая ошибка в VS:

> **System.InvalidOperationException не обработано пользовательским кодом** Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту,
>   так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.

**Решение проблемы:**

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData("http://example.com/Slide_" + slideId + ".png"));
image.EndInit();
image.Freeze();
```

Спасибо [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) за помощь с проверкой локальных ресурсов. Ваш ответ был ближе всего к решению проблемы.

P.S. Сама проблема была не с доступом к элементу UI из другого потока, а с блокированным ресурсом который поток из `Singleton` класса пытался передать в UI. Т.е. нужно было взять картинку как стрим поток и на основании его создать ресурс. А далее как в MSDN описании `Freeze()` для совместного использования. Надеюсь кому-то пригодится, т.к. проблема не единичная, по крайней мере, на EN SO.

Comment: Кажется, вы создаете картинку вне UI потока. Пробовали это `BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); .... и все иниты для картинки` создавать в UI потоке, а в доп треде только записывать созданную картинку в массив?

Comment: @tym32167 как это должно выглядеть в коде? Пробовал добавить ещё один ивент и делегат, но получаю NPE при обращении к нему в Singleton классе. Естественно до UI даже не доходит.

Comment: `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); .... и все иниты для картинки})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект ImageSource обычно может использоваться только из потока, в котором он был создан. Необходимо вызвать `image.Freeze()` после завершения загрузки изображения (т.е., вызова `image.EndInit()`), если вы хотите использовать его в других потоках (после этого он станет неизменяемым). См. [Freezable Objects Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview)

---

Также, если ImageSource указывает на HTTP URL, его загрузка осуществляется асинхронно. Поэтому перед вызовом Freeze нужно дождаться его загрузки, при этом выполняя обработку событий WPF в потоке. Для этого понадобится вспомогательный метод:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

public static void DoWpfEvents()
{
      DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
           new DispatcherOperationCallback((f) =>
           {
               ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false; return null;
           }), frame);
      Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
 }
```

Ожидание можно выполнить так:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri("http://example.com/image_" + slideId.ToString() + ".png");
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.EndInit();

while (image.IsDownloading) { DoWpfEvents(); Thread.Sleep(100); }                     

image.Freeze();
```

Но лучше воспользоваться советом из [соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867086/240512) и создать изображение в основном потоке (он на самом деле работает, если все сделать правильно):

```
BitmapImage image=null;

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.UriSource = new Uri("http://example.com/image_" + slideId.ToString() + ".png");        
    image.EndInit();

});
```

Comment: Т.е. картинка должна создаваться в UI потоке и не важно будет она использоваться в нём или нет? Вся инициализация с загрузкой должна быть в *.xaml.cs? В итоге я прихожу к тому, от чего ушёл пытаясь разгрузить код обработчика окна. До этого у меня всё работало, но была проблема с задержкой вызванной загрузкой всех изображений. В новой модели класс запускается задолго до инициализации окна, что должно было убрать артефакты.

Comment: @Rootware я же написал, можно, но необходимо перед этим заморозить его (из того потока, который создал).  "*запускается задолго до инициализации окна*" - но не до инициализации объекта Application в WPF, я надеюсь?

Comment: Singleton класс инициализируется в Splash окне где происходит загрузка всей необходимой информации с сервера. Как правильно я понимаю, такого рода классы не имеют привязки к месту инициализации. Это просто объект. Там как раз получается задержка в 3-5 секунд чтобы обновить кэш картинок для слайда. А по поводу Freeze() я это пробовал добавлять в Singleton класс. Не получается ничего, кроме старой модели, когда в MainWindow.xaml.cs был на DispatcherTimer была реализована вся логика кэширования и смены слайдов. там вообще всё "топорно", в смысле примитивно, было. Вы можете показать ваш вариант?

Comment: @Rootware Не знаю, у меня работает Freeze. Беру ваш код, добавляю в методе slideCache строку `image.Freeze();` после `image.EndInit();` и никаких исключений. Единственное что, я поменял URL на локальные пути к файлам (не знаю, важно ли это).

Comment: С `image.Freeze();` если использовать путь вида `new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Slide_" + slideId + ".png");`, то всё работает отлично. Стоит изменить на HTTP ресурс (с локал хостом не пробовал) вида `new Uri("http://example.com/Slide_" + slideId + ".png");` сразу выдаёт ошибку. Есть возможность как-либо избежать кеширование на диск картинок из интернета? Собственно всю предыдущую неделю я эти эксперименты проделывал, но только без локальных ресурсов. Поэтому ваш совет и совет других отклонил, т.к. как оказалось это работает только с локальными/встроенными ресурсами/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. решение добавил в конец вопроса.

Comment: @Rootware По поводу загрузки из HTTP, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Любое взаимодействие с UI из потока, отличного от потока UI, должно вызываться в UI потоке. Проверяйте весь код, где есть какое-либо взаимодействие с UI контролами, например, присвоение картинки и используйте Dispatcher.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => imageSlide1.Source = CreateImage());
```

Comment: Не работает. Ошибка возникает как раз в потоке UI на строке `this.imageSlide2.Source = image;` как раз через Invoke. В поиске с подобным вопросом у многих возникает ошибка именно с `BitmapImage`. К тому же, в приведённом мной коде подобная схема работает с многими контролами, но с `Image` нет.

Comment: Вообще я бы посоветовал уйти от устаревшего Thread к async\await и MVVM .

Comment: Что плохого в `Thread` по сравнению с `async`? Да к тому же это вряд ли решит мою проблему.

Comment: Плохо в Thread все, проблему решит точно.

Comment: Не решило. Идентичная ошибка. Есть ещё варианты для `Singleton` класса и потоков в нём?

Comment: а.. поставьте breakpoint на invoke