# Ошибка ImageBrush

Tags: wpf, xaml

Существует некий софт, имеющий возможность использовать скины, которых хранятся в Xaml файлах

Я хочу поменять одно из свойств, которое записано как SolidColorBrush

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ССBackground"
                 Color="#1e1e1e"
                 po:Freeze="true" />
```

на картинку

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg"
            x:Key="CCBackground"
            po:Freeze="true" />
```

Софт валится с

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Можно ли это как-то обойти?

Comment: А что такое `po:Freeze="true"`?

Comment: Одно из свойств

Comment: Причем если поменять SolidColorBrush на LinearGradientBrush то все отлично

Comment: *Одно из свойств* — очень информативно, спасибо. Если бы это было какое-то штатное свойство, я бы не спросил. Попробуйте убрать установку этого свойства, если падать перестанет — приведите код класса с этим AP.

Comment: В том-то и дело что никакого когда нет. Есть только xaml файл

Comment: Как вам тогда помочь? Обращайтесь к разработчику приложения.

Comment: Я потому и спрашиваю. В чем разница между Solid,Gradient и Image кистями. Почему первые две работают а третья нет...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WPF невозможно обновить элемент окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866956/wpf-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0)